# Azure Active Directory B2C user signup without redirect (non interactive)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am building a native iOS application and want to use AADB2C as identity provider where users login, signup, reset their passwords etc.

I cannot figure out a way to let users signup with AADB2C (or regular AAD for that matter) without redirecting them to a (customizable, but still) microsoft website. To be perfectly clear: I want to let customers create user accounts on AAD from a native iOS form without redirecting them to a website, preferably via REST request. (Like here under "Create consumer user accounts": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet)

Comment: What's the problem when you using the Azure AD Graph REST to create a user for the Azure AD B2C tenant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you create users from an iOS app? 
**Yes, using the Graph API** as per [the article you showed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet). You can only create local accounts at this time though.

However **you need to be very careful about how you do it** given that currently, the ability to create users requires Directory.ReadWrite.All permission, which also allows all other sorts of operations. You should NOT put the client ID and client secret for an app with these permissions in your iOS app. Rather, you would need to create a backend service that exposes an API for your iOS app to call for user creation.

However, **more importantly, what you WON'T be able to do is SIGN IN the users without a redirect** (which is what the B2C sign up policy does). In order to do this from your own UI without redirects, you would need Azure AD B2C to support [Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential) so that you can, after creating the user, use this flow to sign them in and get a token.

Note: You would also need to disable Email Verification so that you can leverage the user account right after user creation. You can set this in the Sign-up policy or Sign-up/Sign-in policy via *Page UI customization > Local account sign-up page > Email Address > Require Verification > No*

Lastly, as an FYI, there's a feature in the works in Azure AD B2C: [Customer Owned Domains](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains), which, paired up with UI customization, would allow you to have sign-up/sign-in pages that you can look like your own and have a URL of your own, with no trace of Microsoft for your end users to see.

Comment: Thanks very much, that clears things up. Would it be possible do achieve what I want using "regular" AD? That supports _Resource Owner Password Credentials Flow_, right?

Comment: "Regular" Azure AD does support the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow, that's correct. Do keep in mind that this is either fragile or expensive because there are lots of things that will either break you or complicate your code, for example if multi-factor authentication kicks in, if the user's password expires and needs to be renewed, if some of the identity protection mechanisms kick in. All these things are handled by the the Microsoft pages.

Comment: This is especially relevant if you're doing this for a directory that you do not own (either your IT department owns or you're doing a multi-tenant app).

Comment: Nice answer, which contains everything you need in order to implement a "Pure REST" integration (also the hint for the backend service, which is anyway needed as proxy because some services are blocked by CORS - (example refresh token))